# Incremental calls to Z3 on UFBV with and without push calls

Tags: z3

I am running Z3 on UFBV queries. Currently the query contains 2 calls `check-sat`.
If I put `push 1` just after `check-sat`, Z3 solves the query in 30sec. If I don't put any `push 1` at all, thus have two calls `check-sat` without any `push 1` between them, then Z3 solves it in 200sec.
Interesting. Any specific reasons or just a coincidence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Z3 3.x has a "strategy specification language" based on tactics and tacticals. I'm not "advertising" that yet because it is working in progress. 
The basic idea is described in this [slide deck](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/cp2011.pdf).
We have a different built-in strategy for each logic. The strategies usually do not support incremental solving, because they may apply transformations that use a "closed-world" assumption. Example, we have transformations that map 0-1 linear integer arithmetic into SAT. Whenever Z3 detects that the user "wants" incremental solving (e.g., multiple `check-sat` commands, `push`&`pop` commands), it switches to a general purpose solver. In future versions, we will provide more features for controlling Z3 behavior.

BTW, if you have two consecutive `(check-sat) (check-sat)` commands, Z3 not necessarily enters in incremental mode. It will enter only if there is an `assert` or `push` command between the two calls.

Now, suppose your query is of the form: `(check-sat) <assertions> (check-sat)`, and your second query is of the form `(check-sat) <assertions> (push) (check-sat)`. In both cases, Z3 will be in incremental mode in the second `(check-sat)`. However, the behavior is still not the same. The incremental solver "compiles" the asserted formulas to an internal format, and its behavior is affected if a `push` command has been executed. For example, it will use a more efficient encoding of binary clauses only if there is no user scope. By user scope, I mean, the number of `push` commands - number of `pop` commands. It does that because the data-structure used in the more efficient encoding does not have an efficient undo/inverse operation.

Comment: Both versions of the query are incremental. The difference is in having `push`. Non incremental query is solved in 8sec.) Does `push` change tactics? Or it is due to different _program flow_ in case of push? (e.g. additional copying that could change order of constraints..)

Comment: Z3 automatically assumes it is in incremental mode if `push` is used.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, Leo. But Z3 assumes both queries to be incremental (since in the first - 2 calls to `check-sat`, in the second - 2 calls to `check-sat` and also `push`. So..what is the difference?:)

Comment: I see, you are comparing `(check-sat) ... (check-sat)` with `(check-sat) ... (push) (check-sat)`. I will update the answer.