# Z3 C# API assertion removal

Tags: c#, z3

I am using Z3 solver and adding and tracking specific assertions. I am carrying out my analysis in itterations. I was wondering if it is possible to remove one specific assertion and replace it with another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but only indirectly, either via assumptions (which can be disabled later), or by using push/pop. See also the following posts and the links provided there:

[Soft/Hard constraints in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/soft-hard-constraints-in-z3)

[Incremental solving in Z3 using push command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269016/incremental-solving-in-z3-using-push-command)

[What is the benifits of incremental solving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736269/what-is-the-benifits-of-incremental-solving/23739636#23739636)